# Apply common logic to every request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am new in Spring boot security.  I have built a spring boot based web app, there are several endpoints exposed to client.

Now, I would like to introduce some security check logic for every request hitting my endpoints. I mean no matter to which endpoint the request is for, the security check logic is common for every request. That means I need to be able to parse the request object.  How can I achieve this by using Spring Boot Security?

e.g. Can I achieve this by creating my custom authentication provider like below? Would this be applied to all requests? How can get the request object?

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
         // my security check logic, but how can I get the request object?
    }
```

Or am I completely in a wrong direction to achieve this?

Comment: Hello @Leem any special requirements for the security check or you are talking about role-based access or user authentication before accessing the endpoint

Comment: Not role based check , that would be authorization. E.g. check the signature of each request.

Answer (score 1):

## Background

Your authentication provider usually isn't called for every request. It depends on your setup. Usually, for every request, the `Authentication` is loaded from the session. If the user has already authenticated, the filter that checks to see if the client needs to be authenticated (`FilterSecurityInterceptor`) will let the request go through. If not, it might throw an `Exception` that ends up being handled by another filter that performs the redirect to the login page.

The point is that in this typical setup, the `AuthenticationManager` (and therefore your `AuthenticationProvider`) only ends up getting invoked when the request goes through the login endpoint, so it's not usually invoked for ***every*** request.

## Potential solution

Since every request (usually) goes through the entire filter chain, you could put all your logic in a filter:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) {
        // check the request here

        // ...

        // if you want the request to keep going through the filter chain:
        chain.doFilter(req,resp);

    }

}
```

Then you just add it to the chain in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    ...
    http.addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), CrsfFilter.class);
}
```

There are countless ways to customize the filter to your needs. You could add an `AccessDecisionManager` to handle the situation where the "authentication" in your filter fails, or an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, or you could move it further down in the `FilterChain` to have the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` take care of your `AuthenticationException`s... etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get current you can use this static method.

`HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()) .getRequest();`